# (Discord.py) Send a message to all guilds

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I've been trying to send the same message to all the guilds where my bot is, but nothing has worked and I haven't been able to find something similar in the docs. Is this posible? How can I do It?

Edit: ok, lets's imagine that what my bot does is checking a news webpage like BBC or any other. The bot would be checking the web every five minutes and sending links of the news to those guilds where .start (for example) was executed. The way I've implemented this, was by a command that generates a single loop for each guild, the idea was to have just one loop for every guild.

Comment: You might want to be careful about "sending messages to every X" when it comes to Discord. Whether it's DMing every member in a server or sending a message to a channel in every guild, it could be considered API abuse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for guild in bot.guilds:
    await guild.text_channels[0].send(<message>)
```

This will get the first text channel found in the guild and send a message to it.

You can get the bot from a context variable by typing `ctx.bot`.

Answer (score 3):

```
class send_all(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot = bot
        
    @commands.command() 
    async def send(self,ctx,*message_to_send):
        guild = ctx.message.guild
        output = ' '
        author = ctx.message.author
        for word in message_to_send:
            output += word
            output += ' '
        for member in self.bot.get_all_members():
            try:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="",colour = discord.Colour.green())
                embed.add_field(name="**From server:**",value= guild.name)
                embed.add_field(name = "**From Mod/Admin:**",value = author.name)
                embed.add_field(name="**Message:**",value = output)
            #   await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                
                await member.send(embed=embed)
            except (discord.HTTPException, discord.Forbidden,AttributeError):
                continue
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.