# Get all guilds' id for registering slash commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, command

I'm developing a discord bot and I want to add slash commands to it. So I didn't found anyway to add all guild ids to a list or sth else. Could you please help me find a way to do that? (discord.py)

Comment: Are you using a fork of discord.py? Specifying guild id in order to use slash commands is not necessary.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ShwetaK, that's an external library. [Please don't link to external sites that don't contain code.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code) The question is unclear and most probably doesn't need a whole new library/framework. Also, the OP probably wants to get the IDs of all guilds the bot is in and add them to a list, not install py-cord. Avoid commenting "`pip install <library>`" when the OP doesn't ask for it or if that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you are asking for.

There is a method to get the bot guilds
using [`bot.guilds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.guilds).

> In order to send a message to all guilds:
>
> ```py
> for guild in bot.guilds:
>     await guild.text_channels[0].send(<message>)
> ```
>
> Quoted from [AlexINF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59096307/19313724)

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) It's better to avoid answering poorly-phrased and unclear questions. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293931/should-one-answer-terribly-poor-questions and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368284/users-answering-bad-questions-instead-of-teaching-the-op-that-question-is-bad. It's better to comment in such cases. The OP probably wants to add these to a list, not send messages to them. Also, please see [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [how to edit](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)